# get all the elements that has no value with a specific class in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, class

I had certain elements like with same class as below which will be generated in a loop or something dynamic generation

```
<div>
  <input id="name" class="validate" name="name" type="text" value="Andrew">
  <input id="address" class="validate" name="address" type="text" value="Newyork">
  <input id="place" class="validate" name="place">
  <input id="city" class="validate" name="city">
  <input id="door" class="validate" name="door">
</div>
```

So i had the above elements, in which some has values and some does n't has values,
So i need to make an array of the elements that has no values, so that i can loop through each element and can do some stuff like adding data, deleting etc.,

So how to collect all elements in an array that has `no value` with a specific class like `validate` in jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

returns the elements without a value :

```
var elems = $('.validate').filter(function() {
    return !this.value.length;
});
```

return the elements without an actual `value` attribute

```
var elems = $('.validate').filter(function() {
    return this.getAttribute('value') == null;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

With this selector :

```
$('.validate:not([value])');
```

If it's for validation purpose, you need to filter :

```
$('.validate').filter(function(){
    return $.trim(this.value) == '';
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$("input.validate:not([value])");
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6UX6r/1/